# Android: SimpleDateFormat prints duplicates across multiple fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The structure of my application is a `FragmentTabHost` which contains a `Fragment`, inside that`Fragment` is a `ViewPager` which allows the user to scroll through child Fragments.

```
(FragmentTabHost -> Fragment -> ViewPager -> Fragment)
```

Within the final Fragment, the date of the data it is processing should be displayed.

Here is the code I am using to create the date:

```
String format = "MMMM F";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateString = (formatter.format(item.getDate("date")) + suffixForDayInDate(item.getDate("date")));
Log.d("RAW DATE", item.getDate("date").toString());
Log.d("AFTER FORMATTING", formatter.format(item.getDate("date")));
```

**Output:**

```
D/RAW DATE: Mon Mar 07 17:00:00 MST 2016
D/AFTER FORMATTING: March 2
D/RAW DATE: Sun Mar 06 17:00:00 MST 2016
D/AFTER FORMATTING: March 1
D/RAW DATE: Sat Mar 05 17:00:00 MST 2016
D/AFTER FORMATTING: March 1
D/RAW DATE: Fri Mar 04 17:00:00 MST 2016
D/AFTER FORMATTING: March 1
```

Please tell me someone has a clue here.

Comment: Okay, so what were you expecting? (And why are you calling `item.getDate("date") four times? Your code would be clearer if you extract a local variable...)

Comment: Note that due to using UTC, your first value is effectively Tuesday March 8th, which is indeed the 2nd Tuesday in March, hence "March 2".

Comment: It's *also* unclear what all the fragment description has to do with anything. Are you actually asking "Why is SimpleDateFormat producing this output for this input?" or something else? The whole question is really unclear at the moment.

Comment: My mistake was simply that I was using "F" with the expectation that it would retrieve the day of month, when instead I should have been using "d". Was not paying attention the docs enough. Thanks for your comments guys.

Comment: Please clarify the question then - it's still very unclear, and the fragment part still seems entirely irrelevant. (Fundamentally, the lesson here should be "Always check the SimpleDateFormat documentation carefully against your pattern if it's not behaving as you expect it to.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below line, you are using the incorrect Format to parse your Date. It should be `dd` instead of `F`.

```
String format = "MMMM F"; /* Correction Required */
```

From JAVA Docs:

> F     Day of week in month
>
> d     Day in month

You should correct it as follows:

```
String format = "MMMM dd";
```

Here is the sample code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date dt = parser.parse("Mon Mar 07 17:00:00 MST 2016");
    
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
    String date = formatter.format(dt);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Input:

```
Mon Mar 07 17:00:00 MST 2016
```

Output:

```
March 08
```

Comment: It wasn't until I read this over that I noticed my problem. After taking a second look at the android docs I realized F = day of week in month, what I really wanted to be using is "d" (day of month) rather than "F". Very foolish mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: @Frogger Your Welcome! I'm glad it was useful.

Comment: The OP already *has* a `Date` object. There's no indication that any extra parsing is required. All that's wrong is the OP's format, which you've corrected but not mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I didn't realized that `item.getDate(...)` is returning the Date Object. Updated the solution.

Comment: I'd edit the parsing out of the code, too, but it's at least a lot better now. Shame the question doesn't actually say what's desired... I rarely answer questions which amount to "I didn't read the docs for SimpleDateFormat" unless there's some subtlety...